# Не могу разобраться с добавлением участников через бота в ТГ

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Мне нужно, чтобы бот добавлял участников   через их ID в определенный чат telegram
Пользуюсь библиотекой telebot

Использую команду:

bot.promote_chat_member(chat_id, id_user)

Где chat_id - id чата, в который я хочу добавить пользователя,
id_user - id пользователя

Выдаёт ошибку:
Request: bots can't add new chat members

При этом, бот находится в этом чате, имеет абсолютно все права, а также является администратором и имеет все права администратора

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)